# Get all specific day in specific end date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, filter

I am trying to get all day (input by me) in a specific end date (input by me).

example :

I have `day 1` and I have `end date 10/12/2021`

beginning from new Date():

```
output must be: 1/10/2021 1/11/2021 1/12/2021
```

`day 1` for this month is not included because we are in `day 20` and `day 20 > day 1`

Same, I chose `day 20 (example)` and `end date = 19/12/2021` day 20 in end date not included because `day 20 > end date day`

I have already tried that as simple using if condition, but not great work because in this case, I have 8 conditions!

I want a simple code that works for this situation.

Comment: Please provide the condition you have tried it with.

Comment: If I undestand you correctly:
1. If (today) > day 1 or today > end date day than you do not want to include this month in output.
2. You only want to output one date within a remaining months (with beginning day input)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope that is what you wanted. You can simplify it more if you want.

```js
const getRemainingDates = function(beginningDay, endDate){
  const today = new Date()
  const [endDateDay,endDateMonth,endDateYear] = endDate.split("/");
  const remainingMonth = endDateMonth - (today.getMonth()+1);
  for(let i = 0; i <= remainingMonth; i++){
    if(i === 0){
        if(beginningDay>today.getDate() && beginningDay>endDateDay){
          console.log(`${beginningDay}/${today.getMonth()+1+i}/${today.getFullYear()}`)
        }
        else {}
    }
    if(i !== 0)console.log(`${beginningDay}/${today.getMonth()+1+i}/${today.getFullYear()}`)
  }
}

getRemainingDates(21,"12/12/2021");
console.log()
getRemainingDates(1,"12/12/2021");
```

Comment: this will not work for dates not in the same year

Comment: genius answer, thank you! @Phaki